# Why is JQuery index() returning 1 for the first element?

Tags: jquery

In the following line of code, a call to the index() function for the first element in a set returns 1. Why does it not return 0?

```
var firstBlockIndex = $( '.block' ).first().index();
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this on `jsfiddle`?

Comment: It does return 0, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75jo1o8v/). This line is fine, it's something else you are doing wrong.

Comment: `$( '.block' ).first().index('.block');` but then there is no purpose for checking index here

Comment: @MarkoGrešak It not necessary returns 0, it can returns any value depending HTML markup and previous sibling elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the HTML block below:

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span class="block"></span>
    <span class="block"></span>
</div>
```

Then

```
$('.block').first().index();
```

returns 1 because

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Within the `<div>` block there are 4 `<span>` tags. The `first()` one with class "block" is the second tag. Thus it's index is 1 as `index()` is zero-based ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/index/)).

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd8L8vym/)

---

To get the position of an element relative to all matched elements, you can pass in a selector or element to `index()` to get the index of some narrowed-down selector within the set. Consider this HTML block:

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span class="block"></span>
    <span class="block"></span>
    <span class="block special"></span>
</div>
```

Then

```
$('.block').index( $(".special") ));
```

will return 2 because the span with class "special" is the 3rd element in the group of elements of class "block".

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b02jwbsy/)

Comment: Oh, I see! Okay, if I may ask then, what do I change to get the element to return its position in the set containing only itself and its siblings?

Comment: To get the position of the element relative to all matched elements, you can do this: `$('.block').index(  $('.block').first()  )`. Pass in a selector or element to get the index of some narrowed-down selector within the set. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y0r4sh8y/

Comment: Stack Overflow is strange sometimes ... my answer says the same, is a little older, but got downvoted while your answer got upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`index()` returns the index of an element relative to its siblings, not relative to the other selected elements (see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/)).

Added code snippet to show the behavior:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#result').text($('li.block').first().index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="firstList">
  <li class="noblock">First item</li>
  <li class="block">Second item</li>
  <li class="noblock">Third item</li>
</ul>
<ul id="secondList">
  <li class="noblock">First item</li>
  <li class="block">Second item</li>
  <li class="noblock">Third item</li>
</ul>

Index of first li.block element:
<span id="result"></span>
```